# Nested unordered list with hover

Tags: html, css

I have this (simplified) navigation:

```css
.ctmenu {
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

li:hover > .ctmenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <span class="ctmenu">CT Menu</span>
        <a href="#">Main page</a>
        <ul class="menu sub">
            <li>
                <span class="ctmenu">CT Menu</span>
                <a href="#">Sub page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I hover an li, the direct child .ctmenu should be visible. That works, but I only wan't the element that the mouse is currently on to show .ctmenu. When I hover "Sub menu", .ctmenu for "Main page" is also visible, because I'm hovering that too.

I'd prefer a CSS-fix only, but javascript/jQuery can be okay.

**EDIT:**

I made a little mistake in my first example that I can see from the answers is important:

The `.ctmenu` is before the `a` in the structure and with a `float:right`, so I can't use the `a + .ctmenu` selector. Is there an equivalent the other way around?

Comment: `.menu.sub li:hover > .ctmenu` this will work

Comment: The menu is dynamic and with more levels than shown here, so this will not work. Also your code will not match "Main page".

Comment: @Pete just curious: how can flex help me here?

Comment: @pete okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one extra div after LI tag. Please check below example

```css
.ctmenu {
        display: none;
        float: right;
    }

    .ct-div:hover > .ctmenu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <div class="ct-div">
            <span class="ctmenu">CT Menu</span>
            <a href="#">Main page</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu sub">
            <li>
                <div class="ct-div">
                    <span class="ctmenu">CT Menu</span>
                    <a href="#">Sub page</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because this is a CSS-only solution, this will be the correct answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.ctmenu { display: none; }

li a:hover + .ctmenu, .ctmenu:hover  { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Main page</a><span class="ctmenu">C Menu 1</span>
    <ul class="menu sub">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub page</a><span class="ctmenu">C Menu 2</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not going to work for morethan one .ctmenu elements inside li.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.ctmenu { display:none }
li a:hover+.ctmenu,
.ctmenu:hover {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Main page</a>
    <span class="ctmenu">Demo 1</span>
    <span class="ctmenu">Demo 2</span>
    <span class="ctmenu">Demo 3</span>
    <span class="ctmenu">Demo 4</span>
    <ul class="menu sub">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub page</a>
        <span class="ctmenu">Demo 1</span>
        <span class="ctmenu">Demo 2</span>
        <span class="ctmenu">Demo 3</span>
        <span class="ctmenu">Demo 4</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not going to work for morethan one .ctmenu elements inside li.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML structure doesn't change, you can do it with **JavaScript**, because there is **no** parent selector in CSS.

With the usage of `mouseover`, `mouseout` and `classList`, you can do something like:

```js
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
var items = menu.querySelectorAll("li");

[].forEach.call(items, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.children[0].classList.add("active");
  });

  item.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.children[0].classList.remove("active");
  });
})
```

```css
.ctmenu {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <span class="ctmenu a">CT Menu</span>
    <a href="#">Main page</a>
    <ul class="menu sub">
      <li>
        <span class="ctmenu b">CT Menu</span>
        <a href="#">Sub page</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```